Disable [Enter] in comment field
My IME allows me to choose from several hanzi and commits the selected hanzi by typing [Enter]. At the moment I have to edit the comment for every hanzi I enter (which also means I can write a comment for at most 5 minutes).
We had the same discussion on Japanese.SE.
I would ask for the [Enter] button to be disabled for the comment fields on the main site.

Done.
The same fix that was done on Japanese SE has been configured for the main site.

Fantastic, thank you very much! (Since I've only been using this site for 2 days, I hope there are no experienced users that thought of this behaviour as being a feature.)
